# Redis doesn't seem to check password anymore after first successful password verification

Tags: web-services, redis, passwords

I am using Windows Redis service (Redis 3.0.504) as my cache server, and enabled the password verification by configuring the variable "requirepass" with a password.

But when I test it, it seems that redis server stops checking password for all the clients after a successful password verification from any client, feels like a successful password verification simply unlocked the Redis server for all.

In my implementation, I am using a ServiceStack web service as a wrapper to the IRedisClient, and only expose my webservice to cache clients so that I can keep redis server for local access only due to its security vulnerability.

In the web service, I am using castle windsor for the dependency injection of an instance of PooledRedisClientManager object for the request to obtain a redis client (IRedisClient). The code is similar to the following:

In web service init:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager("password@localhost:6379"));
```

In service controller, to obtain a redis client as below:

```
public MyServiceResponse Any(MyServiceRequest request)
{
     ...
     var redisClientsManager = HostContext.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>();
     using (IRedisClient redisClient = redisClientsManager.GetClient())
     {
         redisClient.Password = request.Password;
         ... 
     }

     ...
}
```

I am not sure whether Redis is incapable to enforce the password verification, or there is a flaw or an issue in my solution/implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Redis enforces its password with the [AUTH command](https://redis.io/commands/auth) where once validated, it allows access to all Redis operations for the connection from that point on.

In ServiceStack.Redis the password should be [specified on the Connection String](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-connection-strings) where it will ensure every new connection to Redis is authenticated with the password specified. You wont need to be concerned with specifying the password in your App's logic as it's automatically provided for each new Redis connection created in the pool.

Note: the recommended API for accessing Redis in ServiceStack Services is to use the `base.Redis` property, e.g:

```
public object Any(MyServiceRequest request)
{
     ...
     var value = Redis.GetValue(key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mythz for the answer! It seems my design makes my WebService as only client to Redis, therefore, as long as the webservice connects to Redis server successfully from the beginning, it is a verified client from that point on. And all the external "cache clients" are actually only "different" clients to the web service not to the redis. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @StevenC It's not the client, but the individual redis tcp connections. When using a pooled Redis Clients Manager these redis TCP connections are pooled (and reused) behind the scenes.

Comment: I see. I create an instance of PooledRedisClientManager and saved it for reuse when web service is up, so the pooled redis client manager connects once and reuses the connections thereafter. I am new to Redis cache, so wondering if I want to use the password for authentication for every request, should I recreate PooledRedisClientManager every time for every request?

Comment: @StevenC All Redis Client Managers should be singletons so their pools can be shared. I don't understand why you aren't just configuring the password for the Redis Server in the connection string then leaving everything else as-is? If the redis-server is password protected, all clients accessing it needs to send that same password. I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve by attempting to configure the password at runtime?

Comment: using password is one of our business requirements, sorry can't be too specific on that :) So if I configure the password for the web service, other "unauthorized clients" can then access our redis cache. We have other layers of using SSL and bearer tokens etc. but at the request level, we are asked to use password for every single request.

Comment: @StevenC I'm not asking why you're using passwords, I'm asking why you're trying to send a password for Redis at runtime? the redis-server is configured with a master password, when you're using a Redis Client Manager it takes care of sending the password for each new connection when needed. If you prefer, you can choose not to use a Redis Client Manager and initiate a new `RedisClient` for each new request and resend the password then, but then you'll be paying for the new connection cost per request and I don't see any benefits to this, you're just creating more connections than is necessary

Comment: Yep, just realized that redis client manager is sending password for every connection so that the password does not have to passed with each request.:) And also fully aware of the cost of establishing new connection per request without using redis client manager, that is why I didn't create connection for every single request. Anyway appreciate your help and really learnt something from our discussion. Thanks very much!